# Estimating temperature most accurately with different thermometers

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, statistical-inference

I recently came upon this semi-opened ended question and wanted to think through it with you guys.

> You have 5 measurements from 5 different thermometers, which are unbiased, but
>   each with a different variance. Out of those measurements, how would you ensure that you measure
>   the oven temperatures most accurately?

I personally would take each thermometer and take the temperature $X$ number of times, lets say 40 times (total of $40*5$ times). Then I would calculate the sample $\mu$ and sample $\sigma$ and simulate a normal distribution for each thermometer.

If I see that the measurements are normally distributed, I would use the thermometer with the lowest variance.

I feel like my answer might be too simple and I'm wondering if I should go about it a different way.

Comment: It sounds to me like you answered a different question than the one asked. The question says that “you have 5 measurements,” not that you have five thermometers that you could use multiple times each. Not that the question is entirely clear, though. I might just take the median or trimmed mean of the five temperatures, assuming that the extremes are more likely than not from the thermometers with greater variance and are further from the true temperature than the other measurements.

Answer (score 1):

> You have $n$ measurements from $n$ different thermometers, which are unbiased, but
>   each with a different variance. Out of those measurements, how would you ensure that you measure
>   the oven temperatures most accurately ?

This is related to what is usually called *data validation* or *data reconciliation* (have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_validation_and_reconciliation#Result_validation)).

The most probable value is given by 
$$\widehat{T}=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac {T_i}{\sigma_i^2}\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac {1}{\sigma_i^2}\right)^{-1}$$